# How to delete object using AJAX properly?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

How should I do it? I've built a function and it works but I still getting some errors. What am i doing wrong? I am newbie in AJAX, so please don't be to hard for me :D

Template

```
<a href="{% url 'del_p' %}"><i class="fa fa-trash" id="post-slug-{{   object.slug }}"></i></a></h2>
```

script.js

```
        function delete_post(curr) {

            var slug = curr.attr('id').split('-')[2];
            console.log(slug);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/delete/',
                type: 'post',
                data: {post_id: slug },

                success: function(json){
                    console.log("It works!")
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    alert("Something went wrong" + data);
                }

            })
        }

        $('.fa-trash').click(function () {
            var curr = $(this);
           delete_post(curr);
        });
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^delete/', views.delete_p, name='del_p'),
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def delete_p(request):
   if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
      post_slug = request.POST.get('post_id')
      del_post = get_object_or_404(ImagePost, slug=post_slug)
      del_post.delete()
      return redirect('folders')

   else:

      return HttpResponse(
      json.dumps({"nothing to see here"}),
      content_type='application/json')
```

Errors

```
[23/Nov/2015 16:15:51] "GET /delete/ HTTP/1.1" 500 87099
[23/Nov/2015 16:15:51] "POST /delete/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\socket.py", line 394, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software installed on the host computer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have a bug here

```
json.dumps({"nothing to see here"})
```

This won't work as you're passing a `set` to `json.dumps` while you probably meant some `dictionary` like

```
json.dumps({"result": "nothing to see here"})
```

instead.

---

The other problem that you have is that you have a link and when the user clicks it you're doing an AJAX request, for this to work you would have to make sure that the browser does not navigate to the target `href` of the link, you can do that by changing the event from

```
$('.fa-trash').click(function () {
    var curr = $(this);
    delete_post(curr);
});
```

To

```
$('.fa-trash').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var curr = $(this);
    delete_post(curr);
});
```

[Read more about preventDefault here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Comment: Thanks, I already fix that, but I still getting those errors. In English this error sounds like "ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

Comment: OK then I added the answer to your problem to my comment above.